# Could not verify the copy source within the specified time

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-blob-storage, azure-files

I created simple .net core web api application, in that added a new API empty controller and added the code for getting the image/file from azure file share and uploaded into azure blob storage.

Here is the code I wrote in my controller:

```
 // GET: api/UploadFiletoBlob
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> UploadFiletoBlob()
    {
        // Retrieve the connection string for use with the application. The storage connection string is stored
        // in an environment variable on the machine running the application called storageconnectionstring.
        // If the environment variable is created after the application is launched in a console or with Visual
        // Studio, the shell needs to be closed and reloaded to take the environment variable into account.
        //string storageConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Storageconnectionstring");

        // Check whether the connection string can be parsed.
        if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConnectionString, out storageAccount))
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a CloudFileClient object for credentialed access to Azure Files.
                CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

                // Get a reference to the file share we created previously.
                CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference(fileshareName);

                // Ensure that the share exists.
                if (await share.ExistsAsync())
                {
                    // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
                    CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

                    // Get a reference to the directory we created previously.
                    CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(directoryName);

                    // Ensure that the directory exists.
                    if (await sampleDir.ExistsAsync())
                    {
                        // Get a reference to the file we created previously.
                        sourceFile = sampleDir.GetFileReference(sourceFileName);

                        // Ensure that the file exists.
                        if (await sourceFile.ExistsAsync())
                        {
                            // Get a reference to the blob to which the file will be uploaded.
                            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
                            // Ensure that the container exists.
                            if (await container.ExistsAsync())
                            {
                                CloudBlockBlob destBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceFile.Name);
                                // Create a SAS for the file that's valid for 24 hours.
                                // Note that when you are copying a file to a blob, or a blob to a file, you must use a SAS
                                // to authorize access to the source object, even if you are copying within the same
                                // storage account.
                                string fileSas = sourceFile.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessFilePolicy()
                                {
                                    // Only read permissions are required for the source file.
                                    Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read,
                                    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24)
                                });
                                // Construct the URI to the source file, including the SAS token.
                                Uri fileSasUri = new Uri(sourceFile.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + fileSas);
                                // Upload the file to the blob.
                                await destBlob.StartCopyAsync(fileSasUri);
                                // Write the contents of the file to the output window.
                                Debug.WriteLine("Successfully uploaded the file into blob: {0}", sourceFile.Name);                                 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (StorageException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error returned from the service: {0}", ex.Message);
                return "Failed to upload the file into storage blob";
            }
            return $"Successfully uploaded the file into storage blob: {sourceFile.Name}";
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(
                "A connection string has not been defined in the system environment variables. " +
                "Add a environment variable named 'storageconnectionstring' with your storage " +
                "connection string as a value.");
            return "A connection string has not been defined in the system environment variables. " +
                "Add a environment variable named 'storageconnectionstring' with your storage " +
                "connection string as a value.";
        }
    }
```

But when run my application, then I am getting the below exception randomly at this line of code `await destBlob.StartCopyAsync(fileSasUri);`.

> “Could not verify the copy source within the specified time.”

Complete **Stack Trace** of above exception:

> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.d__4`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.<>c__DisplayClass111_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at DownloadFilesWebAPI.Controllers.DownloadFilesController.d__9.MoveNext() in E:\XXX\XXX\XXX\DownloadFilesWebAPI\Controllers\DownloadFilesController.cs:line 98

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I test in my site and all run well. You could try to upload you storage version to latest and make sure the blob storage's public access level is `container`.

Comment: Could you share the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @JoeyCai, I changed access policy to public level of my blob container but the issue is not resolved

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft, please see my updated question having the complete stack trace of this exception.

Comment: What's your azure storage sdk version?

Comment: @JoeyCai, Currently I used the storage SDK version as 8.1.4.0 but I used the .net core web API application. So, I am not able to install storage SDK from Nuget manually.

Comment: Maybe it no matter with the storage sdk, I upload to 8.1.4 and it also works well. It so depressing.

Comment: What's your storage account, standard or premium? You could try to recreate a standard account to test. And what your account kind, v1 or v2?

Comment: I used the standard storage account with account kind as v1

Comment: If it's a StorageException, could you please share value of the property exception.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation (AdditionalDetails, ErrorCode & ErrorMessage)?

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft, I am getting ErrorCode  is `CannotVerifyCopySource` and ErrorMessage is `Could not verify the copy source within the specified time.
RequestId:4d7c09e4-201e-00a9-7b15-1574c5000000
Time:2018-07-06T10:42:12.3175171Z`

Comment: From the message, it looks like the copy source can't be verified within timeout when the copy request was issued. Have you double check if the source file can be accessed from your side at the meanwhile? Maybe you can add code to try fetching attributes of the source file in catch statement when the error occurs (since it's random and might be hard to reproduce).

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft, The source file will be accessed at my side without any issues. But the issue occurred randomly not consistently.

Comment: I always getting the exception as there is currently a pending copy operation with the same code mentioned in the above question.